# The method onOffSwitch() & checkSwitch() that turns the TV on/off

Tags: java

I unable to switch off the tv and check switch status. Is there anything that i did wrongly?

**Class TV**

```
public class TV{

// instance variables
private int channel;
private boolean flag;
private boolean check;
// constructor
public TV()
{
    //default value
    channel = 1;
    volume =  0;
    flag = false;
}

// accessor
//The method setChannel(int channel) that sets the channel.
public void setChannel(int channel) {this.channel = channel;}

//The method viewChannel() that displays the channel.
public  int viewChannel() {return channel;}



//methods

//The method onOffSwitch() that turns the TV on/off.
public void onOffSwitch()
{

     flag = !flag;

}
```

//The  method  checkSwitch()  that  displays  a  message   whether the TV is on or off.

```
public String checkSwitch(){
    String TVState = "";

    if (flag=true)
        return  "TV is on";
    else
        return  "TV is off";
}

//to String

public String toString ()
{
    return  "Channel: " + viewChannel() + "\nVolume: " + viewVolume() +"\nTVState: " + checkSwitch()  + "\nFlag :" + flag + "\nCheck :"+ check;}             
}
```

**TVAPP**

public class TVApp
{

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    TV t1 = new TV();

    t1.setChannel (2);

    t1.onOffSwitch();//on
    System.out.println (t1.toString ());
    System.out.println ("");

    TV t2 = new TV();

    t2.setChannel (3);

    t2.onOffSwitch();// on
    t2.onOffSwitch();//off
    System.out.println (t2.toString ());
}}
```

Comment: `if (flag=true)` <- typo. you need `==`.

Comment: Id suggest renaming flag to isOn as well - flag is meaningless. isOn is self documenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `if(flag)`, or `if(flag==true)` instead of `if(flag=true)` in your check method

`if(flag=true)` assigns `true` to `flag` and returns `true` resulting in the `true` branch always executing

Comment: if(flag) and if(flag==true) both is work with my code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your `checkSwitch()` method you have

```
if (flag=true)
```

This is assignment and not comparison i.e `=` is an assignment operator whereas `==` is a comparison operation. So when you say

```
if (flag=true)
```

flag is set to true every time. As this assignment is true every time your TV will always be on. Change it to

```
public String checkSwitch(){
    String TVState = "";

    if (flag == true)
        return  "TV is on";
    else
        return  "TV is off";
}
```